# Bounded Variation imply L^1

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, bounded-variation

If a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ is of bounded variation, is it true that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

We need to ask for $f$ to be continuous?

Comment: $f(x) \equiv1$ is not in $L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is false, for example $f(x)=x$ is a function of bounded variations but $\int _ \mathbb{R} |x|dx=+\infty$.